# In C, what is the compatible incomplete pointer type of 3-dimensional array?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, incomplete-type

Suppose that we have a 2-dimensional array `arr` whose element type is `int`. Then we can define a compatible incomplete pointer type of `arr`: `int (*p)[] = arr`. However, if `arr` is 3-dimensional array, the similar definition `int (*p)[][] = arr` doesn't work because `p` is a pointer to an array with type of `int []` which is an incomplete type in this case. How can I define the compatible incomplete pointer of a 3-dimensional array? Specifying the array size for last index such as `int (*p)[][4]` doesn't work for an array with different constant size or a variable length array (VLA).

In addition, I want to use this definition inside struct.

Comment: Even with `int (*p)[] = arr` for a 2D, how would you use it?  You wouldn't be able to index both dimensons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define array types with an unspecified number of elements (your `int[]`), but these are incomplete types.  You cannot declare objects with such types.  You can declare pointers to incomplete types (your `int (*)[]`, or `void *`); these are complete types, but you cannot dereference them or perform pointer arithmetic with them. You cannot, however, define an array type with an incomplete element type. That is outside C's model for data types.

In C, an *n*-dimensional array with *n* > 1 is an array of (*n*-1)-dimensional arrays.  **Since array element types must be complete, that means at most the first dimension of a multi-dimensional array type can be unspecified.**

As you observe, you can work around that to some extent by declaring pointers to incomplete array types, but to what end?  The things you can do with such pointers are limited, to the extent that are few uses for them that are not served equally well by `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

C does not support multi-dimension arrays with undefined sizes, you either have to explicitly define array size for 1st and 2nd dimensions, or use a single-dimension array like this:

```
int height = 3, width = 4, depth = 5;
int arr[height * width * depth];

int x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
arr[ x + y * height + z * height * width ] = 15;
```

Or switch to C++ and use `std::vector< std::vector< std::vector<int> > >`.

Comment: Or use `void *` and cast it to the final type when it is known.

Answer (score 0):

You can have this:

```
int a[3][4][5];
int (*p)[][4][5] = &a;
int (*q)[][5] = a;
int (*r)[] = a[0];
```

As in all scenarios of arrays of arrays, the innermost dimension can be omitted to give an incomplete type.